# converting a string into a mathematical operation (ex: "+2.days")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to be able add days or hours to a previously created Item.

The system can add or subtract a set number of hours or days based on attributes stored in the db, :operator (add/subtract), :unit_of_time(hours/days), and :number.

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
Date.today+2.days
```

where "+" is the :operator, "2" is the :number, and "days" is the :unit_of_time but I'm unsure of how to get the interpolated string of attributes to become the actual operator "+2.days".  Any ideas?

(I've poured through the ruby documentation, but to no avail.  Currently, I'm just manually creating of the possible options (4) in nested if/else blocks... yeah it's gross.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `eval`, e.g.:

```
eval("Date.today+2.days")
```

...and then simply use string interpolation to put in the variables. Note, however, that you should only do this if you can be very certain that the values in your database are always what you want them to be; under no circumstances should users be able to change them, otherwise you'll have a major security issue which compromises your entire system.

Using more lengthy methods like the `if` statement you suggested (or a `case` statement) require you to write more code, but they are much more secure.

Comment: Eval! That does it thank you!  Yeah, those variables are heavily tested, but as you mentioned a lengthy if block is more explicit.  So that might not be a bad thing.

Answer (score 3):

All ruby objects have a **send** method which can be used to run a method by name with parameters. Using **send** as well as converting strings to ints (**.to_i**) should suffice.

```
Date.today.send '+', '1'.to_i.send('months') # This works
Date.today.send operator, number.to_i.send(unit) # Generalized form
```

Ruby is beautiful!

Comment: That's perfect, too!  Thank you Chris.  I knew there was a way, just never new how to use "send" correctly.  Thanks

Comment: Sweet, this works great for evaluating expressions in strings when I don't want to use eval: `'cat'.send('==','dog')`